# How did Matlab implement efficient sub-indexing?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, simd

Here is an example:

```
A(I) = D
```

When `I` is either a binary filter or a list of indices

Answer (score 0):

From the matlab [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxarray.html)

> The fundamental type underlying MATLAB® data. For information on how the MATLAB array works with MATLAB-supported variables, see [MATLAB Data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-data.html).
>
> mxArray is a C language opaque type.

Meaning the underlying implementation is not exposed, only an API. The mxArray contains the following information

- Its type
- Its dimensions
- The data associated with this array
- If numeric, whether the variable is real or complex
- If sparse, its indices and nonzero maximum elements
- If a structure or object, the number of fields and field names

As well as a list of access methods which can be viewed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/access-data.html). At some point it boils down to some pointer arithmetic however as outlined above this implementation is not exposed. A good exploration of matlabs internal memory layout can be found [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlabs-internal-memory-representation)